# Can Samsung Smart TV apps run on all IPTV?

Tags: javascript, samsung-mobile, samsung-smart-tv, iptv

I am looking for an universal IDE (SDK) for all IPTV to create my application, that can run on all IPTVs and Smart TV with Touch and non touch interaction gestures as well. Therefore it is to inquire about that application that are created using Samsung Sdk for Smart TV can run on all 3rd Vendors for IPTVs.  I came across one website http://www.perception.tv/perception/clients/set-top-box-clients/  but looking for a universal solution from Samsung SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you use Application Framework from Samsung SDK, they will work only on 2011+ Samsung TV's.

There are several libraries for cross-vendor SmartTV development:

- https://github.com/Boxee/cloudee-couch
- https://developers.google.com/tv/web/
- https://github.com/joshfire/joshfire-framework